# Insert data in 2 tables MyBatis Error Command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, mybatis, mybatis-mapper

I´m trying to insert data in 2 tables, I have mybatis method with 2 single inserts but when I execute it it throws:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Any idea?

Comment: You should post the details. We cannot help you if you don't provide relevant information like mapper statement, SQL in the debug log. ORA-00933 is most commonly caused by a semi-colon at the end of the statement.

Comment: Sorry I already solved it, it was that the mapper had a <if> label and I didn´t see so pl/sql dont like <if> label

Answer (score 0):

solve using in mybatys method pl/sql
{call
declare
begin

end
}